# Why can't a lvalue be resolved to the corresponding object's address, when the object is a bit-value or declared with the register storage class?

Tags: c, lvalue

From C in a Nutshell:

> An  lvalue  is  an  expression  that  designates  an  object, and it
>   can appear on the left side of an assignment operator.
>
> An lvalue can always be resolved to the corresponding object’s
>   address, unless the object is **a bit-field** or **a variable declared with the register storage class**.

1. According to the second sentence from the quote,  when the object is
   a bit-value or a variable declared with the register storage class,
   a lvalue can't be resolved to the corresponding object's address.
   Why is that?
2. Given a lvalue which can't be resolved to the corresponding object's
   address, how can the lvalue designate an object, and appear on the
   left side of an assignment operator?
3. I think that the following three statements are equivalent:

   - a lvalue can't be resolved to the corresponding object's address,
   - a lvalue designate an object,
   - a lvalue can appear on the left side of an assignment operator.

   and either of them can be used as a definition of lvalue. Am I
   right?

Thanks.

Comment: You can address anything that is aligned on a byte boundary, but you cannot address a bit. A bit field is just a set of bits, you can't address it. You could say that you can calculate the offset of the bit in the field relative to the struct that holds it, but that's not the same as giving it an address.

Comment: Registers don't have numeric addresses.  And bit-fields do not have addresses either.  Them's the rules of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum addressability resolution is the `char`. If you want a bit field, that's one or more bits *within* a `char` so cannot have its own address, unless you were to allow addresses like `42.6` which would blow the heads off most coders :-)

Variables with register storage class generally can't be addressed because they're not necessarily stored anywhere in memory - that is, after all, what the register storage class means: try to keep this value in a register.

But, even though you cannot get an *address* for those objects, that doesn't mean you cannot assign to them. For objects held in registers, you just change the register.

And, for bit fields, you can just use the Boolean operations like `and/or` to manipulate *parts* of an addressable value.